# HTML Markup: Write elements textContent via attribute instead of via passing the value as a child?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I'm pretty sure the answer to this is no, but,

**Is there any way to write HTML elements like this:**

```html
<button innerText="This is the button text" />

<!-- INSTEAD OF LIKE THIS: -->

<button>This is the button text</button>
```

---

For an example like this, my request seems unwieldy, but it makes more sense when you have multiple elements that look like this that you're returning via ReactJS.

```html
<button
  className="btn"
  somePropA="Some Value"
  somePropB="Some Value"
  somePropC="Some Value"
  title="Some title"
>
  Some button innerText
</button>

<!-- VERSUS: -->

<button
  className="btn"
  somePropA="Some Value"
  somePropB="Some Value"
  somePropC="Some Value"
  title="Some title"
  innerText="Some button innerText"
/>
```

I'd love to be able to do this for `button`, `span`, etc.

Comment: You could add the attribute value with JS afterwards. With a button `<input type="button" value="Button text">` would do exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu. I considered that, but I don't want to rely on client side JavaScript to make elements work for several reasons. I'm using React and considering writing some code to make drop-in replacements if there's no native way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

With React, you can create a component for Button (or input, or any other HTML element) and **pass the info as props**, like this:

From a **parent component**:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Button from './button'; // This is your button component

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (<Button 
             innerText="Your inner text" // Here, you can pass the text as props. You could also pass a class name, id, etc.
           />); 
  }
}

export default App;
```

From a **child (Button) component**. I'm using a functional stateless component, but you can use a stateful component if you prefer:

```
import React from 'react';

const Button = ({innerText})=>{

  return <button>{innerText}</button>
}

export default Button;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is what I've done for my buttons but I hoped I was reinventing the wheel and there was a native approach I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 2):

That can easily be done using CSS using its [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) and [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) function, like this, and you can target any element with the attribute selector.

*For custom attribute one is suppose to use the `data-*` prefix, so I added that here.*

Stack snippet

```css
[data-innerText]::before {
  content: attr(data-innerText);
}

/* specifically target span base element */
span[data-innerText] {
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<button data-innerText="This is the button text"></button>
<div>
  <span data-innerText="This is a span"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <button>And it only adds the text to elements that have the attribute set</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but seems like it's asking for trouble. I think it would probably be better to just use JavaScript to replace the innerText before resorting to this.

Comment: @Slbox So what trouble do you see? ... and why add an unnecessary workload using script when there is a built-in way of doing what you ask?

Comment: This method makes new pseudo-elements which are separate from the original elements defined in the HTML. The end result is visually correct, but the generated DOM is substantially different. If someone wants to interact with those elements later, they're going to need to work with the pseudo-elements, rather than the base DOM elements.

Comment: @Slbox Yes, it creates a kind of anonymous (pseudo) child element, but won't have an immediate affect on anything, and far from a _substantial_ different DOM. Still, it is your choice, just here to show options.

Comment: @Slbox Just saw your edit. Well, yes, though pseudo elements are inline and will inherit most used properties set on the base element...as you can see in my updated answer

Comment: CSS is supposed to provide layout and formatting instructions, moving content to stylesheets feels messy.

Comment: @Teemu I didn't move content to stylesheets. I did use a _content_ property though, combined with a CSS _function_, which provide a clever way to keep content in markup and styling in stylesheets, which is a completely different story. So how does that get messy when using a _content_ property for content?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with Javascript, but there is no way built into HTML. Your javascript would look something like:

```
document.getElementById("mybtn").value = "Hello";
```

Comment: This is what I figured, but I've been surprised to learn about some features I never knew about and I hoped this might be one of those cases.

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice if there was a way to do that, but I guess it is not a big enough problem for anyone to act on it.

Comment: Yeah it's a visual hierarchy annoyance at worst.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for any element, using any attribute with only HTML and CSS's `attr()` function:

```css
button:after {
  content: attr(any-attr);
}
```

```html
<button any-attr="YOUR TITLE"></button>
```

Comment: Sorry, I see @LGSon posted the same answer while I was writing it :). LGSon's post was the first one and his solution is even better than mine